# What is the word that describes the balancing the situtaion naturally?

Tags: word-request

I am looking for a word that describes the balancing effect of the situation. This word is used when a certain action taken as an output it has advantages from one point of view but also disadvantages from the other point of view.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. You talk about *a certain action taken as output.* Can you tell us specifically what action? What does it mean to take an action as output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the word: **trade-off**

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few words:

(Definitions from Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English)

[**balance out** *phrasal verb*](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/balance-out)

> if two or more things **balance out**, the final result is that they are
>   equal in amount, importance, or effect
>
> *• Sometimes I look after the
>   kids and sometimes John does – it all balances out.*
>
> Examples from the Corpus
>
> • *Sometimes we have a slight loss and
>   sometimes a slight surplus, but over time they balance out.*

[**even out** *phrasal verb*](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/even-out)

> if things **even out**, or if you **even** them **out**, the differences between
>   them become smaller
>
> SYN level out
>
> *• The differences in their income
>   should even out over time.*

[**e‧qui‧lib‧ri‧um**  *noun [singular, uncountable]*](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/equilibrium)

> 1. a balance between different people, groups, or forces that compete
>      with each other, so that none is stronger than the others and a
>      situation is not likely to change suddenly
>      *•The government is anxious
>      not to upset the economic equilibrium.*
> 2. a state in which you are calm
>      and not angry or upset
>      •*She struggled to recover her equilibrium.*

I can also think of **counterbalance** and **equalize** as two other verbs that may come handy for you depending on the context you're going to use them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, my word is like an idiom, a duplexing word, like "nitty gritty", "vice versa"

Comment: @Yirmidokuz *your* word?

Comment: yes the word I am trying to remember, I meant..

Comment: @Yirmidokuz your question doesn’t specify that, and unfortunately we cannot guess what you’re trying to remember if you don’t provide enough context. You’ve asked for “**the word** that describes ...”